# Advanced search with mysql OR statement - Magento

Tags: search, magento, advanced-search

I want to search with the advanced form, but with an mysql OR statement instead of AND statement.

For example I search for product ‘Nokia’ in Productname field and ‘N97’ in keywords field. The search results has to be Nokia OR N97.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to configure it from search settings in admin page

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Type
```

Comment: I tried all three of options but no one gave me the right result. I keep trying.